# Macbook audio produces a crackling sound when listening to music

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I've been listening to some concentration music on Spotify and Youtube on my Early 2015 Macbook Pro 13", and I've noticed the audio is occasionally crackly (I'm not sure if that's the correct word, but I think people know what I mean?). I don't have this issue when I plug in my headphones to my Macbook, so it appears to be an issue with the Macbook speakers.

I noticed this in the past few days, but never before that, so it seems this is a new issue. Also, I do not have this issue when I listen to pop music. It only seems to happen with the concentration (classical) music.

Can anyone advise on how to fix this?

Here's a link to an audio clip I recorded of the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEYkw.jpg. It's most notable about half way through. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology when I say "crackling?"

Comment: Since you have already found out that it only happens with the internal speakers, it is very likely hardware failure, which can only be resolved by repairing/replacing the speakers. Not much to solve here for us.

Comment: @X_841 Could it really be hardware failure, if the issue seems dependent on the genre of music?

Comment: Why would the genre of music have anything to do with software? And yes, Pop music oder dubstep or whatever has a distinctively different frequency range. Further, I would actually think that pop music just covers that crackling better (but since I can't hear it is hard to tell)

Comment: Hardware fail is more likely if you run the volume hard or have ever used any kind of 'audio enhancer' like Boom. Laptop speakers are very fragile & prone to overheating, coil distortion or weakness in the mount area where the floating speaker meets the bodywork. They also don't like getting wet, but presumably you'd be aware if that had ever happened.

Comment: What browser are you using? If it’s not Safari, can you try with Safari?

Comment: @pion For Spotify, I just use the app. For Youtube, I used Google Chrome.

Comment: @X_841. I don't think the pop music is "covering" it. It's actually a very loud crackling sound when it happens.

Comment: I've never used audio enhancer. I think I usually have the volume on medium. I've had the macbook since summer 2016, so it's pretty old. Though last September, I had my macbook's battery replaced, and they had to also replace the keyboard since it was attached to the battery or something, so I'm not sure if the speakers also had to be replaced? I've never spilled anything on my macbook, but I wipe the keyboard weekly with a lysol/clorox wipe.

Comment: Figuring out what **exactly** harmed your speakers is nearly impossible, however, I repeat: If you connect headphones/speakers, bluetooth and with cable, and the crackling sound disappears, it **must** be hardware failure. Also, 4/5 years is not really *old*, but that depends I guess.